# Edges of tikz picture cut off when using shifted scope

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone, bounding-box

I'm drawing a standalone tikz picture and when I compile it one of the edges is cut off. I think it's because I'm using a shifted scope within the picture.  (Edit, it may be due to the `[x=2cm,y=2cm]` scale I have applied to the picture)

```
\documentclass[tikz,varwidth,border=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=2cm]
  \begin{scope}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[shift={(3.5,0)}]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The furthest right part of my picture is being cut off, I suspect the `varwidth, border=5pt]` arguments aren't taking the `shift` (edit: or maybe the scale) into account.

So my question is either:

- Is there a non-manual way of making sure the edges of my picture don't get cut off? (I'm aware of `\useasboundingbox` but would prefer not to use it)
- Is there a better technique than `shift` to construct two pictures which are very similar but offset from one another by some amount? I don't want to have to draw the picture twice with different coordinates. From an editing point of view `shift` is much more efficient.

Comment: Can you make an example that actually demonstrates the problem? Adding something like `\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);` in both `scope`s isn't enough. For the second part you could have a look at using `\pic`s. See chapter 18 in the manual, or the [tag:tikz-pic] tag here on the site.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I've replicated the problem but it might be due not to the `shift` but due to a scaling of the whole picture I have: `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=2cm]`. Now the problem is there when the shift is `{3.5,0}` and the rectangles are `(3,3)` large.

Comment: @user3087409 please edit your post and place the code so that we can just copy paste.

Comment: Why are you using `varwidth` anyway, if you all you have is a `tikzpicture` it's pointless? (And apparently the cause of the problem.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. No idea. Probably blindly copied from a previous answer about standalone tikz pictures. Removing it fixed the problem.  I think this question should/can be deleted now.

Comment: I answered. Might as well keep it around, no need to delete I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is `varwidth`, which in the example you show is completely unnecessary, so just remove it.

With `varwidth`, the content is set in a `varwidth` environment that is `\linewidth` wide. By default, `\linewidth` corresponds to about 12cm. The content in your diagram is 7.5 * 2 = 14cm wide, so you get an `Overfull \hbox (25.28575pt too wide)`. Because `standalone` sets the size of the PDF to that of the `varwidth`, part of the diagram is cut off.